# how does use cglib correctly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to understand cglib. But I am very confused by the below results. Can somebody please help explain it?

When using @Scope(value = "prototype",proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)

```
@Configuration
@Data
@Scope(value = "prototype",proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class DemoCGLIB {
    private int counter;

    public static void main(String... strings) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DemoCGLIB.class);

        DemoCGLIB bean1 = context.getBean(DemoCGLIB.class);
        bean1.setCounter(2);
        System.out.println(bean1.getCounter());

        DemoCGLIB bean2 = context.getBean(DemoCGLIB.class);
        System.out.println(bean2.getCounter());
    }
}
```

singleton bean instance is created and both bean1 and bean2 refer to the same instance. But counter is 0 even after setCounter(2)

[image]

[image]

When using @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)

```
@Configuration
@Data
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class DemoCGLIB {
    private int counter;

    public static void main(String... strings) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DemoCGLIB.class);

        DemoCGLIB bean1 = context.getBean(DemoCGLIB.class);
        bean1.setCounter(2);
        System.out.println(bean1.getCounter());

        DemoCGLIB bean2 = context.getBean(DemoCGLIB.class);
        System.out.println(bean2.getCounter());
    }
}
```

bean1 and bean2 are different. There is no singleton instance created.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In 1st test using
@Scope(value = "prototype",proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)

CglibAopProxy is being used. setter/getter is done in proxy object.

```
xxxBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB
    CGLIB$CALLBACK
        CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor
```

When printing out the beans, there are

```
demoCGLIB : class com.example.demo.bean.DemoCGLIB$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d34f96ce 
scopedTarget.demoCGLIB : class com.example.demo.bean.DemoCGLIB$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ce3d6945
```

In 2nd test using @Configuration, some kind of cglib proxy was created(probably it is to handle Full mode vs Lite mode). It is not AOP proxy. Update is done on the real object.

```
 xxxBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB
        CGLIB$CALLBACK
            ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor                
            ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanFactoryAwareMethodInterceptor
```

@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE) makes it unique each time. Update is done in real object. So each object can have different value.